# find the limit $\frac{\frac{g(y)-g(0)}{y}-g'(0)}{y}$ as $y \to 0$

Tags: calculus

I was asked to find the exact form of the limit

$$\frac{\frac{g(y)-g(0)}{y}-g'(0)}{y}$$

as $y\to 0$ without using L'Hospital's rule or the Taylor's theorem.
I tried to solve this using the mean value theorem but I failed. Here's my try:
By the mean value theorem, there exists some c between $y$ and $0$ such that

$$\frac{g(y)-g(0)}{y}=g'(c)$$
so what we're dealing with would become

$$\frac{g'(c)-g'(0)}{y}$$ and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without L'Hospital's Rule or something equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Define $h(y)$ to be $g^\prime(0)$ if $y=0$ and $\frac{g(y)-g(0)}{y}$ otherwise, so $h$ is continuous at $0$ and you seek$$L:=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{h(y)-h(0)}{y}=h^\prime(0).$$For $y\ne0$,$$h^\prime(y)=\frac{yg^\prime(y)-g(y)+g(0)}{y^2}.$$This has $y\to0$ limit$$-L+\lim_{y\to0}\frac{g^\prime(y)-g^\prime(0)}{y}.$$Hence$$L=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{g^\prime(y)-g^\prime(0)}{2y}=\frac12g^{\prime\prime}(0).$$

Comment: Sorry, but how do we know that h is differentiable?

Comment: One can prove that the limit in question is $g''(0)/2$ under the assumption that $g' '(0)$ exists. However such a proof requires the use of L'Hospital's Rule or something equivalent. Your approach assumes that $h' $ is continuous at $0$.